# Error editing remarks subsection in documentation

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

I was having a look at the [C# Expression Trees](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/75/expression-trees) documentation page.

I noticed the [Creating expression trees](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/75/expression-trees#t=201611231125479490624&a=remarks-creating-expression-trees-4) looked a bit strange - in particular the '*compiler magic* `code bock` *expression tree API*' looks very out of place. Attempting to edit this section and the one above (which also exhibits this out-of-place code block) yields the following error:

[image]

The other subsections are able to be edited just fine

Comment: Wow. Look at all those edit/share icons too. Something is definitely wrong. I'm putting this on our call for next week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeaaaaah, so... about those subsections edit icons.  They're gone now.

We'd wanted to allow remarks to be edited in "chunks" ala Wikipedia, but it never quite worked as smoothly as we'd hoped.  Markdown parsing gets kind of weird around headers, and inline HTML makes everything nastier too.  There's also some pretty good evidence that most users ignored that option, or didn't understand it.

So that feature has been disabled.  We've kept the ability to *link* to particular sections, as that's considerably less difficult (just parsing HTML) - and probably more useful.

Comment: The formatting issue appears to still be present - Are the issues related? I've attempted removing the escaped asterixes - but it doesn't seem to help. I can't find anything wrong with the actual source which could be causing the problem. The preview of the topic while editing looks fine, however.

Answer (score 5):

I tried to reproduce in dev. It seems the problem is that HTML headers trigger edit/share icons that don't actually work. On our test environment, I edited in a pointless header to a random Remarks section:

```
<h1>Pointless header</h1>

Subroutines get their arguments to magic variable called  `@_`. While
it doesn't have to be unpacked, it's recommended, as it helps
readability, and prevents accidental changes as arguments of `@_` are
passed by reference (can be modified).
```

That also created an extra edit icon, which doesn't work:

[image: Pointless header is pointless.]

However, the top edit icon (the one next to the Remarks header) *does* work. So you can fix errors if you pick the correct icon.

Needless to say, we should remove the excess icons.

Comment: Great - that seems to work. In regards to the malformed text - it appears it's due to some `*`s littered throughout the post. When editing, the preview looks fine, so it's hard to tell what's actually causing it. On a second look - editing out a `*` used for a footnote doesn't improve the situation